# Find modems attached to a system with nodejs

Tags: node.js, node-modules

On C#,
I can simple use `new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_POTSModem");` with the power of WMI and find out all connected modems.

How can i do the same on nodejs ? i tried node-usb but it doesn't render any serial port no nor a indication as to what kind of a device it lists.

Comment: Your question leaves a lot of room for guessing. For example it seems you are talking about Windows?

Comment: i would like a universal solution, I already have a windows C# version but i need to run on a rasberypi, i figured nodejs would be the best solution to go with.

Comment: `The Win32_POTSModem WMI class represents the services and characteristics of a Plain Old Telephone Service (POTS) modem on a computer system running Windows.` It's a Windows method for Windows machines, you will be hard pressed to find it outside of C# or F# or the Windows ecosystem.